# How long may I preserve a caramel sauce?

Tags: caramel

How long can I preserve in the fridge a sauce made of 11 oz. caramel, 1/2 cup butter and 2 T cream?

Comment: Just listing the ingredients is not enough information to arrive at a reliable answer. Fridge temperature and container will affect this as well. As a 'rule of thumb' I would look to 'best by' dates on your cream and butter and go with which ever is soonest...but that would still be acting with an abundance of caution.

Comment: probably safely about two weeks at least. sugar preserves.